# What is the point of the Sphinx highlight_language config option if code-block:: doesn't have an optional argument?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

What is the point of the Sphinx highlight_language config option if code-block:: doesn't have an optional argument?

It says that it sets the default hightlight_language, but if every time that you specify code you need to state the language, why does it need the config option?

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** From the logs when I remove the argument for codeblock.

```
C:\c\Sponge\SpongeDocs\source\plugin\scheduler.rst:25: ERROR: Error in "code-block" directive:
1 argument(s) required, 0 supplied.

.. code-block::

    taskBuilder.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Yay! Schedulers!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to set an unknown language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation is a little bit vague here. In fact `..code-block::` directive should only be used if you want to specify language explicitly for some reason. For default you should use a simple `::` block:

> Examples of Python source code or interactive sessions are represented using standard reST literal blocks. They are started by a `::` at the end of the preceding paragraph and delimited by indentation.

(Source: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html)

It will look like this:

```
::

    var hello = "Hello, World!";
    console.log(hello);
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the `code-block::` directive, specifying the language is optional.

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html#directive-code-block), the default language highlighting is for python. With setting the `highlight_language`, you can change this, e.g. to have c code highlighting when using a `code-block::` without specifying a language.

Comment: C:\c\Sponge\SpongeDocs\source\plugin\scheduler.rst:25: ERROR: Error in "code-block" directive:
1 argument(s) required, 0 supplied.

.. code-block::

    taskBuilder.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Yay! Schedulers!");
        }
    });

Comment: on which sphinx version are you and what are you exactly building?

Comment: A local fork of https://github.com/SpongePowered/SpongeDocs/ with highlight_language = 'java' added to the conf. "Created using Sphinx 1.3.3."